# Use grep to delete multiple instances of string but keep one instance

Tags: python, grep

I have a text file where the content looks like this:

```
[**] [1:1384:8] MISC UPnP malformed advertisement [**]
[Classification: Misc Attack] [Priority: 2] 
03/10-14:33:41.431255 192.168.1.111:40533 -> 255.255.255.255:1900
--
[**] [1:1384:8] MISC UPnP malformed advertisement [**]
[Classification: Misc Attack] [Priority: 2] 
03/10-14:34:11.421186 192.168.1.111:54602 -> 255.255.255.255:1900

[**] [1:1384:8] MISC UPnP malformed advertisement [**]
[Classification: Misc Attack] [Priority: 2] 
03/10-14:34:11.421186 192.168.1.111:54602 -> 255.255.255.255:1900
```

This file can have up as many of this kind of alert as possible, however, I would like to search through the file and only keep one instance of this alert, keeping the report document short and neat.

I was thinking grep to search for the [1:1384:8] and delete all the alerts with this string except one. I am however unsure how to do this, if anyone knows how to or can point me to a tutorial to show me, I am doing this from inside a Python script aswell.

Expected output is to take the duplicate sections of three lines and only leave one section of three lines. Turning above into:

```
[**] [1:1384:8] MISC UPnP malformed advertisement [**]
[Classification: Misc Attack] [Priority: 2] 
03/10-14:34:11.421186 192.168.1.111:54602 -> 255.255.255.255:1900
```

Having only one instance in the report.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to print only the lines which has the string `[1:1384:8]` ?

Comment: Say like above I have two cases where the line has the string [1:1384:8], I don't need both lines printed just the one.

Comment: are the three lines considered one section?

Comment: Yeah sorry, thats why I thought grep for using -B and -A or just -C to keep the section itself, should have explained that.

Comment: @AndrewStewart i'll ready to provide a grep answer also. Could you provide the expected output?

Comment: Made an edit to question regarding expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `open` built-in function:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    file_lines = f.readlines()

cont_lines = []
for line in range(len(file_lines)):
    if "[1:1384:8]" in file_lines[line]:
        cont_lines.append(line)

for idx in cont_lines[1:]: # skip one instance of the string
    file_lines[idx] = "" # replace all others

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(file_lines)
```

Which will remove all the instances of the line, except one, completely.

Turning:

```
[**] [1:1384:8] MISC UPnP malformed advertisement [**]
[Classification: Misc Attack] [Priority: 2] 
03/10-14:33:41.431255 192.168.1.111:40533 -> 255.255.255.255:1900
```

Into:

```
[Classification: Misc Attack] [Priority: 2] 
03/10-14:33:41.431255 192.168.1.111:40533 -> 255.255.255.255:1900
```

Comment: Getting an error of:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alterText.py", line 26, in <module>
    f.writelines(file_lines)
IOError: File not open for writing

Comment: Yeah I seen the 'r' myself and changed it to 'w' after asking.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you want to identify each error, and assuming just taking the last section is okay, then you can do the following to keep a line with `[**]` at the start, and the following two lines as the remainder of the section, eg:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('data.txt') as fin:# 
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in fin)
    errors = {line:list(islice(fin, 2)) for line in stripped if line.startswith('[**]')}
```

Gives `errors` as a `dict` as:

```
{'[**] [1:1384:8] MISC UPnP malformed advertisement [**]': ['[Classification: Misc Attack] [Priority: 2] \n', '03/10-14:34:11.421186 192.168.1.111:54602 -> 255.255.255.255:1900']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sections always have three lines:

```
seen = set()
from itertools import islice

with open("in.txt") as f, open("temp.txt", "w") as temp:
    for line in f:
        # use  all [1:1384:8] as identifier
        spl = line.split(None, 2)[1] 
        # if we have not seen one already write the whole section
        if spl not in seen:
            temp.write(line)
            temp.writelines(islice(f, 2))
        else:
            # else skip a section
            list(islice(f, 2))
        seen.add(spl)
```

Comment: The `None` in the `islice`'s are redundant

Comment: @JonClements,  yep, I don't know why but I always put them in.